# What is the simplest way to check if a character is found within a variable in BASH?

Tags: bash, if-statement, find

I need to check if a variable contains a particular character, for use in an if-conditional in BASH, e.g.:

```
if [ "①" is in "$numbers" ]
then
    echo "Found."
else
    echo "Not found."
fi
```

If `$numbers` is "These are some numbers 1232", it returns "Not found.", but if "①" is found anywhere in the line, it returns "Found."

I have been using `$numbers | grep -c ①`, then checking if the output is greater than "0", but it seems there must be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right hand side of a comparison can be a pattern:

```
if [[ $numbers = *①* ]] ; then
```

Answer (score 3):

As long as it's bash and doesn't need to be posix:

```
if [[ "$numbers" =~ ① ]]; then
  echo "Found"
fi
```

Comment: Could someone explain why/how this works?

Answer (score 2):

For a posix solution, use a `case` statement in place of an  `if` statement:

```
numbers="①"
case "$numbers" in
    *①*)  echo "Found it." ;;
    *)   echo "Not here."  ;;
esac
```

This solution will work under `dash` which is the default shell (`/bin/sh`) for scripts under Debian-influenced distributions.